# dotenv not working after transcompile with Babel

Tags: babeljs, dotenv

I have code reading .env using dotenv that is working in dev but after transcompiling with Babel the values from process.env are undefined. I created a sample program to illustrate the problem which is below.

If I'm in projectRoot and run

```js
npm run start-w
```

then

```js
console.log(process.env.VAR1)
```

prints the value 'var1Val'

However, if I do

```js
npm run build
cd dist
node index.js
```

the value of VAR1 is 'undefined'.

**index.js**

```js
import 'dotenv/config'

console.log('VAR1', process.env.VAR1)
```

**.env**

```js
VAR1=var1val
VAR2=var2val
VAR3=var3val
```

**.babelrc**

```js
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
  ]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "dotenv.node-babel",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.3",
    "dotenv": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/node": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.3",
    "@types/dotenv": "^6.1.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.11",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "clean-dist": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "npm run-script clean-dist && babel . -d dist --ignore node_modules",
    "start": "babel-node index.js",
    "start-w": "NODE_ENV=devLocal nodemon --exec babel-node index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have a .env file in your build directory, try creating one. I guess that's why the environment variable is undefined.